# Find the original function in a summation

Tags: summation

I have the sum

$$S=\frac 12 \sin x$$

and need to find the original function to this summation equation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x)=S$$

I am using the math software Maple, but can't solve this equation there. Is it possible to find the (or an) original function $f(x)$?

Comment: You need to specify how $f(x)$ depends on $n$. If there is no dependence on $n$, as your notation indicate, then there is no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition) that you can use:
$$
\sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}.
$$
Now of course just put a $\frac{1}{2}$ in front.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\sin(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2(2n-1)!}x^{2n-1}.
\end{align}
$$